# How to dynamically add filters to an array based on user input in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, dynamic-arrays

I want to have code that can add dynamic filters to an array and then the array run through a .filter that then checks if all the filters are true:

```
var checks = [item =>item.indexOf("e") == -1, item =>item.indexOf("r") == 0];   
var words = ["roast", "wings", "chive", "pests", "rhyme"]
var filteredArr = words.filter(item => checks.every(f => f(item)));
```

I want it to take two inputs like "r" and the column it should be in (0) and add `item =>item.indexOf("r") == 0` to the checks array.
The problem I have been running into is that when creating arrow functions to push into the checks array, the variables don't compute now because it is an arrow function. Ex:

```
var value = "r"
item =>item.indexOf(value) == -1
```

does not work because it will stay as value and not the value the variable is.

```js
var value = "r"
var checks = [item =>item.indexOf(value) == -1];
var words = ["roast", "wings", "chive", "pests", "rhyme"]
var filteredArr = words.filter(item => checks.every(f => f(item)));

console.log(filteredArr);
```

I have looked through many other questions but they never are able to add filters like I am describing. I was wondering if there is a fix for this problem or another way to add checks to an array dynamically.

Edit:

```
var words = ["roast", "wings", "chive", "pests", "rhyme"];
var checks = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    var value = "r"
    var column = i%5;
    checks.push(item =>item.indexOf(value) == column);
}
var filteredArr = words.filter(item => checks.every(f => f(item)));
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Is it possible for the filter that I pushed to include the i%5 value?

Comment: `item =>item.indexOf(value) == -1` should work just fine. And did you mean to use string literals for your `words` array, or are those all independent variables? (If so, please edit to show what they contain)

Comment: As you can see, the code works.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Instead of adding item =>item.indexOf(value) == -1 i want it to add item =>item.indexOf("r") == -1. I want it to add the check based on the variable value. So if the variable value was "n" it would create a check: item =>item.indexOf("n") == -1

Comment: That will work. If you have `value = "n"`, that is the check it will carry out.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes but I want it to not have the variable value in the check so that if the value variable changes to make a new check, the other check would still work

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me. Please explain how this doesn't work for you.

```
var value = "e";

var checks = [item =>item.indexOf(value) == -1, item =>item.indexOf("r") == 0];   
var words = ["roast", "wings", "chive", "pests", "rhyme"]

// prints roast
console.log("answer:"+words.filter(item => checks.every(f => f(item))));

value = "o";

// prints rhyme
console.log("answer:"+words.filter(item => checks.every(f => f(item))));
```

BTW are you making a wordle solver? Because I made one just this morning in Python ;)

Comment: yes lmao :D But if this code was in a for loop or something and the value variable was not always going to stay the same it would not work, is there a way for it to add the check with no variable name and just the value?

Comment: @Philyshark7 variable capture in JS closures is complicated. Try switching your for-loop to use `let` instead of `var`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/312407

Comment: And by the way, it's important to post a complete working program that reproduces your problem. If your original problematic code has a for-loop, your Question should contain that same for-loop, etc.

Comment: Thanks, added a for loop example. My question was if it was possible to add the check with no variable name and the value of the variable instead and the answers I got were that it was already working which is not what I asked. The for loop is an example to show why having the value in the name would be a problem.

Comment: it matters if you declare the variable as `var value` vs `let value`.  You used neither -- I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: Let doesn't fix the problem I am trying to fix, that the i value will not be part of the check